# extend the given probability measure for finer sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> For a binomial stochastic process with outcomes $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4\}$ at time $t=3$ (assuming the process starts at $t=1$):
> $(a)$ Write each $\omega_i$ in terms of 'H' or 'T'. and write down the basic partitions of the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F_2$ and $\mathcal F_3$.
> $(b)$ Define the probability measure $\mathbb P$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_2$ by, $$\mathbb P(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\})=\frac23,\quad\mathbb P(\{\omega_3\})=\frac16,\quad\mathbb P(\{\omega_4\})=\frac16$$
> Extend $\mathbb P$ from $\mathcal F_2$ to $\mathcal F_3$. Is your extension unique? Justify.

#### My approach

$\Omega=\{\underbrace{HH}_{\omega_1},\underbrace{HT}_{\omega_2},\underbrace{TH}_{\omega_3},\underbrace{TT}_{\omega_4}\}$ and partitions of the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F_2$ and $\mathcal F_3$ might be $\mathcal C_2=\{\{HH, HT\}, \{TH,TT\}\}$ and $\mathcal C_3=\{\{HH\}, \{HT\}, \{TH\},\{TT\}\}$ because $\mathcal F_2=\sigma(\mathcal C_2),\: \mathcal F_3=\sigma(\mathcal C_3)$. So, I need to extend the probability measure for a finer sigma algebra,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\Omega)&=1\\
\mathbb P(\{HH\})+\mathbb P(\{HT\})+\mathbb P(\{TH\})+\mathbb P(\{TT\})&=1\\
x+y+\frac{1}{6}+\frac16&=1\\
x+y&=\frac23
\end{align}
$$

Let $\mathbb P(\{HH\})=x=\frac{2}{6}$ and $\mathbb P(\{HT\})=y=\frac{2}{6}$. Now, we can talk about the probability for any $A\in\mathcal F_3$. Basically, I guess it because I need to ensure $\mathbb P(\{HH, HT\})=x+y=\frac{2}{6}+\frac{2}{6}=\frac23$. I think this extension is unique but how to explain it?

Is my approach correct? Can I improve it further? Any kind of suggestion/help will be appreciated.